# SELECT from one table, JOIN on another table, ORDER BY a third table?

Tags: sql, select, join

I have three tables for a forum application I am creating:

- `boards` - represents a collection of posts, `is_deleted` boolean
- `posts` - represents some text as well as a collection of comments
- `comments` - represents some text

My goal is to display a certain number of all posts from boards that are not marked as deleted, ordered by the last comment made to the post (and then when the post was created). The current query I have to do this is:

```
SELECT
  posts.*,
  (SELECT created_date
   FROM comments
   WHERE comments.post_id = posts.id
   ORDER BY comments.created_date DESC
   LIMIT 1) as last_comment
FROM posts
JOIN boards ON boards.id = posts.board_id
WHERE boards.is_deleted = 0
ORDER BY
  last_comment DESC,
  posts.created_date DESC
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 0
```

which works very well, but I don't actually need `last_comment` other than when I use it to order the results, so it feels like I'm running an additional SELECT for little reason. Is there a better way to do this?

### Edit 2013-05-18:

Fooling around with it a bit more, I believe I have a query that doesn't rely on nested SELECT statements:

```
SELECT
  posts.*
FROM posts
JOIN boards
  ON boards.id = posts.board_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments
  ON posts.id = comments.post_id
WHERE
  boards.is_deleted = 0
GROUP BY
  posts.id
ORDER BY
  comments.created_date DESC,
  posts.created_date DESC
LIMIT 4
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: 1. Depending on database you run you can have concretised views for the last comment which would make query faster but updates would be heavier 2. you can make the data unnormalized and store the last comment inside the post table and 3. if you are afraid about performance then you should probably move `SELECT` to `JOIN` (unless db do it automatically) and work with the keys to make the query efficient (foreign keys etc.). I would not care so much about query itself as long as it readable and db optimizer can deal with it.

Comment: Thanks, Maciej! I was messing with it in the time between posting and now, and I just edited my original post with an updated query I believe might be better. It converts the nested `SELECT` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` along with a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

At that time is there no better way to do this then via another select statement.

You could put the select statement on a different position, like:

```
select p.*, com.created_date from posts p, comments com, boards b where b.id = p.board_id
and b.is_deleted = 0 and com.id in (select c.id from comments c where c.post_id = p.id 
order by c.created_date desc limit 1) order by com.created_date desc, p.created_date desc 
limit 4 offset 0;
```

Query planners are designed to optimize the where-clause, hence if possible will I try to make only select statements in the where-clause. 
If you would do it without that second select statement, then can you do that only if you store this information in the posts-table at the moment the data is saved.
Then would you have to add a column to the posts-table, with for instance the name 'last_comment' and put the creation time of the comment in that field. In that case can you replace the second statement by the ordering of the field 'last_comment' in the posts table.
However, then you change the table due to a functional requirement that might change in the future. I would not advise you to do that. Each table or view is a different object and the SQLs take care of the ever changing functional requirements.